# Is it possible to display notes from a midi file in real-time using Tone.js?

Tags: javascript, midi, audio-player, tone.js

I want to display the notes in realtime when the midi file is beign played using tone.js, but all i can do is display them before the track plays.
Is there anyway to display them alongside the track using tone.js or any other ways?

**All the below code does is log all notes info when the play button is clicked.**

```
    async function initiateMidi() {
        const midi = await Midi.fromUrl('src\\static\\saliha-ya-khdoud-ettefeh.mid');
    
        const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
        synths.push(synth);
    
        const now = Tone.now() + 0.5;
    
        midi.tracks.forEach((track) => {
            track.instrument;
            const notes = track.notes;
            notes.forEach((note) => {
                const noteTime = note.time + now;
                synth.triggerAttackRelease(note.name, note.duration, noteTime, note.velocity);
                console.log(`Note: ${note.name}, Time: ${noteTime}, Duration: ${note.duration}`);
            });
        });
    }
```

Any help on how will this work in note.js or any other way I should go about this would be appreciated and thanks in advance

**Edit :**
I added a setTimeout function to display the notes in time but I still there is a way to do this using note.js

```
    async function initiateMidi() {
            const midi = await Midi.fromUrl('src\\static\\saliha-ya-khdoud-ettefeh.mid');
            const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
            synths.push(synth);
    
            const now = Tone.now() + 0.5;
    
            midi.tracks.forEach((track) => {
                const notes = track.notes;
                notes.forEach((note) => {
                    const noteTime = note.time + now;
                    const noteDuration = note.duration;
    
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log(`Note: ${note.name}, Time: ${noteTime}, Duration: ${noteDuration}`);
                    }, noteTime * 1000);
    
                    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note.name, noteDuration, noteTime, note.velocity);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: I am guessing that `synth.triggerAttackRelease` creates a "stack" of notes to play, based on those `note.duration` and `noteTime` values ...? Then you will probably have to implement something similar for the _display_ of your individual note values - using the `noteTime` in a `setTimeout` call ...

Answer (score 0):

See https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Transport.html#schedule.
You can use `Transport.schedule()` which works almost like `setTimeout()`. In general, it is better to use the `schedule()` method when scheduling audio events in Tone.js. This ensures that the events occur at the correct time in the musical timeline, regardless of the tempo.